# Monitor Kubernetes cgroup issue using prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana

How can we setup alert on grafana, When a pod is in init state due to cgroup memory allocation issue of Docker ?

Comment: kube-state-metrics produces metrics on state which would allow you to alert if something is in a particular state longer than expected.

Comment: It will show me that pod is in init state for more then 5 mins. and give me alert. But how can I monitor based on particular events like cgroup memory allocation issue.